# Java code giving error,: Syntax error or token "1", < expected

Tags: java, android, http

i am trying to make an HTTP POST request to Hackerrank API but the code is not compiling and giving the error Syntax error or token "1", < expected. One of the POST parameters is 'testcase' which needs to be a string but this is where eclipse gives an error. If i don't put " " around the 1 it works fine but now the Hackerrank API gives response code : 400 because testcase needs to be string. I can't figure out as to how to resolve this problem. Can someone please guide me.

Thanks in advance. This is the code:

```
package com.us.ABC;

import java.io.BufferedReader;  
import java.io.DataOutputStream;  
import java.io.InputStreamReader;  
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;  
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://api.hackerrank.com/checker/submission.json";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "source=print 1&lang=5&testcases=["1"]&api_key=hackerrank|282807-132|8d62bbbdf90d6a790747561f031a017b7f6cbbeb";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes in the string literal:

```
String urlParameters = "source=print 1&lang=5&testcases=[\"1\"]&api_key=hackerrank|282807-132|8d62bbbdf90d6a790747561f031a017b7f6cbbeb";
```